# How to get data when I have entry in either table SQL group for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

1. clicks 2.ride

clicks Table 
**id  |  time**

ride Table
**id | timestamp**

I want to get data from both tables group by GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM ride.timestamp)
but I am only getting data if I have entries in both tables for same day but I want data regardless if either table does not have data. I dont know if OUTER join is a answer but mysql does not support OUTER JOIN

My current query which only get data when I have entry present in both tables

````
COUNT(distinct ride.id) AS ride_ads, 
COUNT(distinct clicks.id) AS clicks
FROM ride INNER JOIN clicks ON EXTRACT(DAY FROM ride.timestamp)=EXTRACT(DAY FROM clicks.time)
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM ride.timestamp), EXTRACT(DAY FROM clicks.time)```
````

Comment: ' but mysql does not support OUTER JOIN; - not so - mysql does support left and right outer joins but not FULL JOIN,  you can find plenty of full join equivalents if you search for them

Comment: @P.Salmon can you please help me how can I get the desired result, it would be really helpful if you could provide me SQL query

Comment: Consider a UNION rather than a join.. if you want more add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    DATE(ride.timestamp) AS Day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ride.id) AS ride_ads,
    COUNT(DISTINCT clicks.id) AS clicks
FROM
    ride
        LEFT JOIN
    clicks ON DATE(ride.timestamp) = DATE(clicks.time)
WHERE
    DATE(ride.timestamp) > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY
GROUP BY Day 
UNION SELECT 
    DATE(clicks.time) AS Day, #selecting date from second table since I might have record in this table and I am using group by Day 
    COUNT(DISTINCT ride.id) AS ride_ads,
    COUNT(DISTINCT clicks.id) AS clicks
FROM
    ride
        RIGHT JOIN
    clicks ON DATE(ride.timestamp) = DATE(clicks.time)
WHERE
    DATE(clicks.time) > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY
GROUP BY Day
ORDER BY Day
```